# Rendering Problems: Failed to find the style corresponding to the id -1（3 similar errors）

Tags: android, xml

In my xml document, there are some Rendering Problems, which is Failed to find the style corresponding to the id -1（3 similar errors）. It has nothing to do with the theme, and also it doesn't affect the running. Why?Thx.

[It's the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cV3C.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried changing API level to lower than 23 ?

Comment: Could you share your layout-xml and if necessary your style-xml?

Comment: Thx, it is not the low API level, it's my custome view.I have resolve it.